# Where is the occurrence "start" date in Ical.Net recurring event?

Tags: c#, ical.net

I am using the nuget package Ical.Net 4.2.0 in my C# project. I've created a recurring calendar event and need to identify the start DateTime for each occurrence. I query the calendar with GetOccurrences() like this:

```
var now = DateTime.Parse("2021-09-16T10:00:00");
var later = now.AddHours(1);

//Repeat daily for 5 days
var rrule = new RecurrencePattern(FrequencyType.Daily, 1) { Count = 5 };

var e = new CalendarEvent
{
    Start = new CalDateTime(now),
    End = new CalDateTime(later),
    RecurrenceRules = new List<RecurrencePattern> { rrule },
};

var calendar = new Calendar();
calendar.Events.Add(e);

var startSearch = new CalDateTime(DateTime.Parse("2021-09-16T00:00:00"));
var endSearch = new CalDateTime(DateTime.Parse("2021-09-21T23:59:59"));
var occurrences = calendar.GetOccurrences(startSearch, endSearch)
    .Select(o => o.Source)
    .Cast<CalendarEvent>()
    .ToList();
```

`occurrences` contains five events, but looking for the "start" date, I can only find the event start date. Where can I find the start dates for each occurrence of a recurring event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get them in the actual `Occurrence` object returned by `GetOcurrences` (which you are discarding and actually selecting the source `CalendarEvent`, which is the same for all occurrences), in the `Period.StartTime` property (which is an `IDateTime`, which you can convert to .NET datetime objects)

To get all start date times (as `DateTimeOffset` object):

```
var startTimes = calendar.GetOccurrences(startSearch, endSearch)
                             .Select(x => x.Period.StartTime.AsDateTimeOffset);
```

[See it in action](https://dotnetfiddle.net/R26oUA)

Comment: Perfect answer. Exactly what I was looking for, and I appreciate the example. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can try with **RecurrencePatternEvaluator**

```
var vEvent = new Event {
 DtStart = new CalDateTime(newDateTime(2017, 3, 1, 9, 0, 0)),
 DtEnd = new CalDateTime(newDateTime(2017, 3, 1, 10, 0, 0))
};
var recurrenceRule = new RecurrencePattern(FrequencyDayType.Weekly, 1) {
 ByDay = new IList<IWeekday> { new WeekDay(DayOfWeek.Thursday) }
};
var recurrenceEvaluator = new RecurrencePatternEvaluator(recurrenceRule);
var searchStart = new DateTime(2017, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0);
var searchEnd = new DateTime(2017, 3, 17, 0, 0, 0);
var correctOccurrences = recurrenceEvaluator.Evaluate(vEvent.DtStart, searchStart, searchEnd, false);
```